# Are the skywalkers human?

Tags: star-wars

Talking about Luke and Leia.

Padme - Alien (right?) did not age when Anakin turned puberty.

Because their mom is an alien that doesn't age. 
Does it work like half/half? 
Do they live longer than normal humans?

Comment: [Shmi Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shmi_Skywalker_Lars) was a human who aged normally, what are you talking about?

Comment: Hunh?  Could you provide some backing to this?

Comment: sorry edited my post. i just figured out it was not clear atall.

Comment: I am still confused. What evidence exists that Padme is not a human?

Comment: You've kind of edited it from 'she's an alien' to 'she's an alien (right?)' .... not much of a change.  Why do you think she is not human.  Yes she does not seem to age much in the movies over ... what 10 years?  But some people just age well.

Comment: Is this even real? I'm being punked...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Main_Page) [Shmi Skywalker](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shmi_Skywalker_Lars) is a human, so she'd age at a normal rate and her child (Anakin) would be a human.

I'm not clear where you got your information that she was an alien that didn't age, but there's nothing to back that up and everything in the movies and Extended Universe says and works like she's human.

---

Now that you've changed to clarify that you're referring to Luke and Leia's mother, that would be [Padmé Amidala](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Padm%C3%A9_Amidala).  While she's from Naboo, she's considered human, as a perusal of the Wookieepedia article linked to above will reveal.

As for not aging, during time we see her, in the prequel trilogy, she is quite young.  While she's elected Queen at the age of 13, she does, at that time, look closer to 18 or 19.  It's also extremely likely, in order to increase the confidence of Nabooians, that makeup was used to make her look older than barely pubescent.  At the time of her death, she is 27.  While it's hard to believe she didn't age much between Episodes I and II, many humans don't appear to age much from 17 or 18 years old until their mid 20s or so.

While this does not eliminate questions, it does put a "reverse spin" on them, making it more of an issue about why she aged so quickly so that, at the age of 13, she looked closer to 20.  Not showing many signs of aging from about 18-27 is believable, but it is puzzling why she'd age quickly enough to look post-adolescent when she's just 13.

Comment: just edited my post. sorry for the miss interpretation

Comment: "why she'd age quickly enough to look post-adolescent when she's just 13". - Makeup. Planet-sized-budgeted makeup.

Comment: @DVK: Yes, that's true, but I'm trying to stay in universe.  Unless you're saying the humans on Naboo wanted their queen to look more mature, so they used all that make up.  (Which I would find perfectly credible.)

Comment: @TangoOversway - correct (well, it applies BOTH in and out of universe)

Comment: maybe they compute age using the Logarithmic function? :)